# How do employees of the Ministry of Magic get paid?

Tags: harry-potter, money

Like Muggles, wizards do have to work or have some other source of income (family money, like the Potters and Malfoys). And every time we see a business transaction in the HP wizarding world, we see actually physical currency exchange hands.

How do large organizations, like the MoM, pay their employees? Do they get a sack of galleons every payday? Does Gringotts transfer the galleons from the MoM vault to the individual employees' vaults automatically? Is there a wizarding equivalent of a cheque?

Comment: Under the table?

Comment: Umbridge took Slytherin's locket from Mundungus as payment for letting him off the hook for selling stolen goods,  so that's one example of how they get paid

Comment: @user13267 No, that's an example of a corrupt official taking a bribe. Not sure that counts at all.

Comment: It must be said that although Jo Rowling did a somewhat reasonable job of developing other parts of the legendarium, on anything related to math or economics the omissions are continental in size.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the fact that Molly Weasley needs to *collect* her pittance from the family's bank vault (when it could be easily, and more conveniently have been stored in a small snoke-skin purse at the family's home), it seems most likely that salaries are transferred directly from a central MoM account to the account/vault of the MoM employee.

> The vaults were reached by means of small, goblin-driven carts that
> sped along miniature train-tracks through the bank’s underground
> tunnels. Harry enjoyed the breakneck journey down to the Weasleys’
> vault, but felt dreadful, far worse than he had in Knockturn Alley,
> when it was opened. There was a very small pile of silver Sickles
> inside, and just one gold Galleon. **Mrs Weasley felt right into the
> corners before sweeping the whole lot into her bag**. Harry felt even
> worse when they reached his vault. He tried to block the contents from
> view as he hastily shoved handfuls of coins into a leather bag.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets: CHAPTER FOUR — At Flourish and Blotts</sup></sub>

---

As far as cheques are concerned, we see at least one example of these in Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, albeit from a distance where it couldn't possibly be read on screen. A copy of the prop made its way into the [Limited Edition](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_Limited_Edition) boxset.

[image]

And again in the same film, the [Quibbler subscription form](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/File:Quibbler-Spectrospecs.jpg) makes mention of both Gringotts Cheques and [**Postal Orders**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_order), another form of promissory note.

[image]